# YouTube API v3 file_get_contents not works (Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden)

Tags: php, http, youtube, google-api

i have a problem with file_get_contents. I can't get data from googleapis..

allow_url_fopen is **enabled**

```
file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&forUsername=name&key=APIS_KEY");
```

return:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&forUsername=name&key=APIS_KEY): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
```

Server key was generated (On localhost all works, on my VPS not)
I have no idea what i can do.

*file_get_contents on other websites works.*

Could you help me?

Comment: Woah, i did it... in some case, my server send request from ipv6, not from ipv4.
Google didn't know it ( me too ) and they blocks the stream.
So reason was IP Address, not IPv4 but IPv6.

Comment: How did you changed the ipv6 to ipv4 then?

Comment: I didn't. I added ipv6 to whitelist pool. (It was very fast reply, obviously)